# Disable generation of deleting destructor

Tags: c++, gcc, embedded, destructor, freestanding

I am developing a program for embedded system that will not use dynamic memory allocation. How can I prevent the GCC from producing *deleting destructor* (the destructor with `D0` in its mangled name)? It will be never called.

I think that there is even no need to have deleting destructors, since the *complete object destructor* (`D1` in mangled name) can be called instead along with `operator delete(…)` after it.

In my opinion, there should be some command-line option to disable these destructors.

---

The main problem is that the program calls `operator delete(…)` in the deleting destructor. Since I do not have any heap management, no such function is defined. As a workaround, I could implement `operator delete(…)` that just reports an error, but this would waste memory (unnecessarily large program size) and will not allow me to catch accidental call to `operator delete()` during the compilation.

Comment: "_since the complete object destructor (D1 in mangled name) can be called instead along with operator delete(…) after it._": No, the caller doesn't know the pointer offset to or size of the most-derived object when `delete` is applied to a base class pointer. That's why the deleting destructor exists.

Comment: @user17732522, that thing about inline destrucotrs is nice. If it applies even to virtual destructors, post it as an answer. I will try that.

Comment: *"In my opinion, there should be [X]"* -- gcc does accept contributions...

Comment: @JaMiT, this thing made me think about adding this feature to the GCC as a new CLI option, unless there is a way to do it now. It would cause it to produce non-standard (and non-compatible) object files, but it sounds very useful for some cases in embedded software development.

Comment: @jiwopene Oops, my thought process was a bit wrong there. Even if inline the compiler will of course create the deleting destructor once you create a complete object of the class type. It's necessary since there could be a `delete` on it to one of its bases in another translation unit which doesn't see the inline definition.

Comment: @user17732522, the polymorphic types are allocated using placement new. No `operator new` nor `operator delete` calls are done and I would like to avoid them so I do not need to introduce any heap management just because of few instances of these classes.

Comment: I can perform some workaround very easily, but I am looking for an elegant solution.

Comment: Good point. Maybe that changing the design could solve the problem/clumsiness.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255151/discussion-between-jiwopene-and-user17732522).

Comment: @jiwopene Please note that I made a mistake in my comments and answers. Declaring the `operator delete` overload as `inline` is actually UB.

Comment: @user17732522, thanks for the comment. Knowing that it is UB is very important, in my opinion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The deleting destructor variant exists so that the syntax

```
delete ptr;
```

where `ptr` points to an polymorphic type can work even if `ptr` doesn't point to the most-derived object. The user of `delete ptr;` doesn't know what the offset to the most-derived object or its size is, but it needs to know that in order to call `operator delete` correctly. Therefore there needs to be an indirect/virtual call to a function that knows, which is the deleting destructor.

Unfortunately the compiler has to generate the deleting destructor from such a `virtual` destructor at least for all classes which are used as most-derived objects, since there could be a `delete` expression of that kind in another translation unit that doesn't know about the definition of this most-derived destructor which it must however (indirectly) call.

---

I don't think that you can separate the `delete` behavior of virtual destructors from the ability to do explicit virtual destructor calls and I also don't see any GCC switch to disable the generation of the deleting destructor as a non-standard/ABI conforming option.

So I guess you'll have to avoid virtual destructors. You can get the virtual destruction behavior anyway by forwarding from a `virtual` function:

```
struct Base {
    virtual destroy() noexcept { this->~Base(); }
    // destructor not virtual
};

struct Derived {
    virtual destroy() noexcept override { this->~Derived(); }
};
```

And then instead of `ptr->~Base();`/`std::destroy_at(ptr)` you can use `ptr->destroy()`.

However, this has the problem that you need to assure that `destruct` is properly overriden in every derived class to avoid undefined behavior. CRTP or C++23 explicit object parameters (explicit `this`) may help with that.

You also have the problem that someone might accidentally call the destructor directly, again causing undefined behavior. Making the destructor `private` is also generally not a solution because the destructor is potentially invoked in many situations, e.g. in a constructor of a class that contains the class in question as a non-static member.

---

I originally suggested here to implement the `operator delete` as empty and `inline` in every translation unit to help with removing the calls, however I didn't realize that marking the replaceable deallocation functions as `inline` makes the program IFNDR and so isn't valid. (See [[replacement.functions]/3](https://eel.is/c++draft/replacement.functions#3.sentence-3).)

You can't delete the `operator delete`, because it will be odr-used for the reasons I mentioned above and must therefore viable.

---

LTO might further help getting rid of unused emitted deleting destructors during linking, at least via devirtualization. But I haven't tested.